# Calling Activex button from javascript code

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I am using Activex component to display cctv camera live video on my html page. Every time when I open my page, have to click on play button to start live stream. 
I am trying to start stream automatically when page gets loaded, Is there anyway to capture Activex component click event in javascript ?

```
<OBJECT   
    ID="cam"  
    NAME="cam"
    CLASSID="CLSID:34bO1746-aga1-459e-9e55-g9d2ac709a3" 
    onReadyStateChange="NotifyActiveX(this)"        
    WIDTH="100%"  
    HEIGHT="80%">  
</OBJECT>
```

[image]

Comment: You could try to use the PARAM elements in the OBJECT Element and use the autoStart property. Code as below: `<OBJECT ID="Player"
  CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
    <PARAM name="autoStart" value="True">
</OBJECT>`

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT, where can i get all possible param ?

Comment: please check these documents: [PARAM Elements in an OBJECT Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/param-elements-in-an-object-element), [Adding an Embedded Windows Media Player Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/adding-an-embedded-windows-media-player-control) and [PARAM - Object Parameter](https://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/param.html).